# What entry type would a forum be in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I am creating a references list for a school project and would like to include a forum discussion that I found helpful. The problem is I am not certain which entry type would be most appropriate for biblatex. I was considering @online, there is no real author of a forum discussion, just a bunch of participants, and the documentation says author/editor is a required field.

```
@online{poker, 
title = "Isaac Newton - det heliocentriske verdensbillede.", 
date = "2012-11-28", 
url = "http://www.lalelu.com", 
urldate = "2015-11-01" 
}
```

Comment: **What does the forum policy say on this?!**

Comment: @Rewned I would use **urldate** instead of **urlseen**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't really about how to use TeX or related technologies. Sure, BibTeX is *well* within the scope of this site, but questions like 'what's an appropriate citation format for this resource' are not, sadly. Sites like Academia.SE might be more appropriate, but again beware that this might inherently be opinion-based. (That said, I'm glad you found an answer anyway.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the [biblatex documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

> **`misc`** A fallback type for entries which do not fit into any other category.
>   Use the field howpublished to supply publishing information in free
>   format, if applicable. The field type may be useful as well. author,
>   editor, and year are omissible in terms of § 2.3.2.
>
> **Required fields:** `author/editor, title, year/date`
>
> **Optional fields:** `subtitle, titleaddon, language, howpublished, type,
>   version, note, organization, location, date, month, year, addendum,
>   pubstate, doi, eprint, eprintclass, eprinttype, url, urldate`

I would use the `misc` type and I would ask your supervisor if he wants a specific text for the `howpublished` field. All entry types, therefore also the `misc` type, support the `url` field.